# How to add context menu entries in website projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx, vsix

I'm not able to add context menu entries for website project items.

**How to reproduce the problem:**

1. Create a VS Package project
2. Go to the vsct file and replace the `groups` section with:

   ```
   <Group guid="guidVSPackage1CmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
      <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"/>
   </Group>

   <Group guid="guidVSPackage1CmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
      <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_PROJNODE"/>
   </Group>

   <Group guid="guidVSPackage1CmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
      <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE"/>
   </Group>

   <Group guid="guidVSPackage1CmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
      <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_FOLDERNODE"/>
   </Group>

   <Group guid="guidVSPackage1CmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
      <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_SOLNNODE"/>
   </Group>
   ```
3. Debug the package and see: This will add an entry for the solution, project and project items in a simple C# project. But when I create a ASP.NET website project (File->New->WebSite) I won't get these entries except for the solution item.

I'm sure this must be possible due to the fact, that NuGet has an entry for the website project item. unfortunately, I was not able to extract that piece of code from the NuGet source code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a while I found a solution: (I accidentally looked into the StyleCop source code :P)

```
<Group guid="guidVSPackage1CmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0050">
  <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_WEBFOLDER"/>
</Group>

<Group guid="guidVSPackage1CmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0050">
  <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_WEBITEMNODE"/>
</Group>

<Group guid="guidVSPackage1CmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0050">
  <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_WEBPROJECT"/>
</Group>
```

These are not documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb163231%28v=vs.100%29).

Anyway, I'm curious how NuGet does it, because they have nothing in the `vsct` file, but an entry in the context menu.