# Adding button to solution explorer context menu in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix, solution-explorer

I am building my own extension for visual studio 2010. It contains one command that i want to be available from project context menu in solution explorer:

[image]

The problem is that when i'm trying to place menu button description within the command table (.vsct) like this (using [this one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088469/how-to-add-context-menu-entries-in-website-projects)):

```
<Groups>
      <Group guid="guidChickPublisherCmdSet" id="ChickPublishMenuGroup" priority="0x0100">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_WEBPROJECT"/>
      </Group>
    </Groups>
    <Buttons>
      <Button guid="guidChickPublisherCmdSet" id="cmdidChickPublish" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidChickPublisherCmdSet" id="ChickPublishMenuGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidImages" id="publishImg" />
        <Strings>
          <CommandName>cmdidChickPublish</CommandName>
          <ButtonText>Chick Publish...</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
    </Buttons>
```

it doesn't work for mvc or simple web apps (only for either web sites or single project items).
I have already tried great bunch of guid:id pairs as  values with no success.

Does any one know how to add this command to solution explorer context menu?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (except Web Sites)

```
<Groups>

  <Group guid="guidWizardPackage2010Project" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0050">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_PROJNODE"/>
  </Group>

  <Group guid="guidWizardPackage2010Project" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0050">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_WEBFOLDER"/>
  </Group>

  <Group guid="guidWizardPackage2010Project" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0050">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_WEBITEMNODE"/>
  </Group>

  <Group guid="guidWizardPackage2010Project" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0050">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_WEBPROJECT"/>
  </Group>

</Groups>
```